# Almost all trees have non-trivial automorphism group

Tags: graph-theory, trees, algebraic-graph-theory, automorphism-group

In their paper [*Asymmetric Graphs*](https://users.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1963-04.pdf) Erdős and Rényi proved that almost all trees have non-trivial automorphism group. More specifically they showed that almost all trees contain at least one so-called cherry, i.e. three vertices $i, j, k$ where $i, j$ are leaves, $k$ has degree $3$ and $(i,k)$ and $(j,k)$ are edges.

Unfortunately I'm having some trouble understanding their proof. I can follow the counting argument but fail to understand the following bits, in particular the part where Chebyshev's inequality is used.
I would be very grateful if someone could explain to me the steps in the proof in more detail or point me to some other reference for this result. I haven't found this in any graph theory book.

I have linked the original paper above. The relevant bit starts on page 18 of the pdf.

Comment: What is $M(\ldots)$ in $(5.2)$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I guess that's the expected value and $D^2$ is the variance.

Comment: Mcavaney https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/bulletin-of-the-australian-mathematical-society/article/note-on-limbless-trees/B54172286889D6232B729B420F056F61 has a short proof that almost all trees contain a given limb; tis immediately implies the result of Erdős and Rényi.